# line graph over time has gaps. fil gaps in line graph. reportbuilder 3.0

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I've a line graph over time . The data is grouped by week. For some weeks I don't have any data, what produces gaps in the line. Now I would like to connect the gaps. I found the option to insert empty points into the graph for missing data. But as far as I see it requires a defined colour. But the graph should be dynamic and automatically use the graphs colour.

Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must ensure the type of  hart is a contiguous, linear type this way the line does not stop and start with gaps.

[Empty and Null Data Points in Charts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239390.aspx)

**Edit:**

Also there is a recommended formula you should use in this instance for RB 3.0.

[Empty Points(1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_pfe_blog/archive/2009/05/28/chart-behavior-difference-in-sql-reporting-services-2008.aspx)
or
[Empty Points(2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207051.aspx)

Comment: Which types of charts in ReportBuilder 3.0 are contiguous?

Comment: Sorry, what means "type of hart"?